# Why is setColumnCount in PyQt5 so slow?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing an application using PyQt5 and wanted to figure out why my application took some time to start up (about 2s). The application contains multiple TableWidgets and calls the setColumnCount method a total of 15 times (on 15 different tables).

After profiling, I have found that my calls to the setColumnCount method represent about 54% of the start up time of my application. I have tried to disable updates on my tables before calling the method but this did not have any effect.

Is this expected behavior ?

EDIT :
I set 3-4 columns for each setColumnCount call. The method is used before any other actions on the table

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        for _ in range(15):
            table = QTableWidget()
            table.setColumnCount(4)

app = QApplication()
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I have timed the example using perf_counter

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableWidget
)
import sys
from time import perf_counter

class WindowWithSetColumns(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        for _ in range(15):
            table = QTableWidget()
            start = perf_counter()
            table.setColumnCount(4)
            end = perf_counter()
            print(f"setColumnCount time : {end - start}")
class WindowWithoutSetColumns(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        for _ in range(15):
            table = QTableWidget()

            

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

print("Total window setup without set column count")
time_start = perf_counter()
window = WindowWithoutSetColumns()
time_stop = perf_counter()
print(f"Time elapsed : {time_stop - time_start}")

print("\n\nTotal window setup with set column count")
time_start = perf_counter()
window = WindowWithSetColumns()
time_stop = perf_counter()
window = None
print(f"Time elapsed : {time_stop - time_start}")
```

Output :

```
Total window setup without set column count
Time elapsed : 0.02483579999898211


Total window setup with set column count
setColumnCount time : 0.6786081999998714
setColumnCount time : 0.0003318999988550786
setColumnCount time : 0.0003051000021514483
setColumnCount time : 0.00027739999859477393
setColumnCount time : 0.00027829999817186035
setColumnCount time : 0.00033849999817903154
setColumnCount time : 0.00029540000105043873
setColumnCount time : 0.00034869999944930896
setColumnCount time : 0.00032079999800771475
setColumnCount time : 0.00033629999961704016
setColumnCount time : 0.0003189999988535419
setColumnCount time : 0.000267100000201026
setColumnCount time : 0.000271100001555169
setColumnCount time : 0.000312700001813937
setColumnCount time : 0.0003088000012212433
Time elapsed : 0.7056196000012278
```

Comment: What's the number of columns you set? Is your table(s) are empty before you call the `setColumnCount()` function?

Comment: I've edited my question to include this information. I set 3-4 columns each time and the tables are always empty when the function is called.

Comment: It looks like `setColumnCount()` call resizes a `QVector` object and inserts items into another `QVector` object. Besides it emits couple of signals that probably trigger the GUI update. As a result it spends additionally 2 secs. on it.

Comment: @Nosullya You must provide a [mre] that demonstrates the behaviour so that others can try to reproduce the problem. All that's required is a simple test-case that reliably shows a delay when `setColumnCount` is called. If you find you can't create such a test-case, that probably indicates the actual problem is elsewhere in your application (i.e. the column-count issue is merely a symptom, not the cause). Some common culprits are e.g. sorting, column-resizing, use of cell-widgets, etc, etc - but without seeing actual code, a proper diagnosis isn't really possible.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the minimal reproducible example to my post, thank you

Comment: @Nosullya That example does not demonstrate in any way the problem you describe. The tables will all be garbage-collected as soon as they are created. But even if they are added to a layout, there won't be any delay. You need to do some realistic timing of code execution to show that there's a measurable performance issue (and print the output so as to show how the test actually behaves on your system).

Comment: @Nosullya I confirm what ekhumoro says above, even after adding the table widgets to a layout and set a proper central widget, the program starts almost instantly, even on my +10 years old computer. I did a further test with 100 tables in a grid layout (which is a bit more complex than box layouts), and the program still opens in far less than a second. Do you **really** get the same issue with the code you've provided? Because the "reproducible" in MRE doesn't just mean that we can run it, but that it also *reproduces the issue*: if it doesn't, then it is *not reproducible*.

Comment: @vahancho resizing a few QVectors shouldn't take that much time (2s), unless the previous row count is *extremely* high (since the insertion is done row by row); the OP also says that the problem exists at start up, meaning that at that point the signals won't trigger any UI update (visual or layout related) that could justify such a delay, *unless* they're not telling us something (and I'm inclined to this possibility), such as also setting a row count and using `ResizeToContents` in the horizontal header along with a badly written delegate that takes too much time in returning its size hint.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have included performance benchmarks. As I said in my original question, I was wondering if creating 15 tables and only setting their row count was **supposed** to take this long. The benchmark example I have provided reproduces the problem I was encountering : The amount time it takes to set the column count on a table being high on my system. In my full application I do set a row count, but since this problem also happens in the MRE provided, I am inclined to believe that setting a row count has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: @Nosullya that profiling is not accurate: it measures the time that also includes the creation of the QApplication, that of the window, the creation and *deletion* of those tables, and the call to `show()`. You should display the values within the creation of the tables and, specifically, the call to `setColumnCount()`, and eventually the overall time with and without the `setColumnCount()` calls.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, I have changed my example to a more detailed one. It seems like the first execution of the setColumnCount method is very slow compared to successive uses.

Comment: @Nosullya I cannot reproduce the problem at all on Linux using Qt-5.15.9 and PyQt-5.15.9 when running the test in a normal console (i.e. *not* an IDE). The total elapsed time is consistently about 0.021 seconds with columns and about 0.017 seconds without.

Comment: @Nosullya As pointed out above, we're not able to reproduce the timings cited in your question. In fact, you're not able too, at least not to that extent (before your previous edit, the higher value was just a bit more than 1s, while in your later tests is way under it). As said, we need to be able to reproduce the issue, and that includes knowing about your environment. Are you using an IDE or a debugger? Are you running a compiled binary? Are you on a VM? It seems quite unlikely that you get those values in normal circumstances, especially after *directly* running the script more than once.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I have tried to run my own example do on different machines and it seems like it might have something to do with windows as my test ran considerably faster on two different computers running linux (debian and arch).